# How to differentiate event handler for handling checkbox change event

Tags: jquery

I have got two parts  of a HTML page .

One is **Search** and another is **Table**

Inside table the ids for  checkboxes will be generated dynamically such as 124 , 125 --- and the check box under search section is of id **searchcheckboxid**

Is it possible to distinguish the event handler when the checkbook is checked or Unchecked for both the sections ??

Means if checkbox clicked inside the  Table

i want to call this event handler

```
$(document).on('change','input[type="checkbox"]' ,function(){

alert('Clicked on Table Checkbox');    

});
```

and if its clicked searchcheckboxid  under search section , i want to call a different handler .

please let me know how to do this ??

http://jsfiddle.net/vxe2d2hh/26/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your selector to target only checkboxes which are descendants of table

```
$(document).on('change','table input[type="checkbox"]' ,function(){
     alert('Clicked on Table Checkbox');            
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cmw8p42t/1/)

---

If the table is static and rows are added dynamically then bind the delegated handler to the table instead of the document object. This will improve the performance since all change events outside of the table will be ignored by the handler

```
$('table').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function () {
    alert('Clicked on Table Checkbox');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cmw8p42t/2/)

Comment: What about adding `:checkbox` instead of `[type="checkbox"]` as a part of example?

Comment: please see this fiddle , http://jsfiddle.net/vxe2d2hh/27/ this is being called for both when clciked on table checkbox

Comment: @Kiran you have `'input[type="checkbox"]'` as selector in second event handler - what else do you expect?

Comment: @Arun , could you please tell me ho to write a handler when clicked on search box

Comment: Arun , i modified my code to this fiddle , http://jsfiddle.net/cmw8p42t/3/ , is it fine to approach this way ??

Comment: Thank you very much , but my event handler are working only wheni use them with document .

Comment: @Kiran there is no need for that since the search checkbox has own id.. just target that without using event delegation....(use event delegation only if the search box is created dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
After seeing your code:

```
$('table').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function () {
    alert('Clicked on Table Checkbox');
});


$('#searchcheckboxid').on('change', function () {
    alert('Clicked on Search Checkbox');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vxe2d2hh/28/